# What is the latest possible point during a pregnancy when a fetus can merge with another fetus?

Tags: pregnancy, chimerism, zygosity, human

### Background

A [Chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(genetics)#Humans) is an organism that is composed of two or more zygotes.  There are several documented incidences of this happening in humans as shown in the cited link.

Since chimeras primarily arise early in pregnancy when one fetus absorbs another, I wanted to know....

## Question

What is the latest point in pregnancy at which a human fetus can absorb another human fetus?